# Primary Group ID Powershell Variable

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to modify my Powershell script to change/replace an Active Directory users Primary Group.  Currently, the PrimaryGroupID is using a hardcoded number but we'd rather have something more... portable.  Is there a way to do a lookup for the specific group by name and input that as a variable into my code below - replacing the "*2131*" primary group ID?

```
# Set named users primary group to "Disabled Users"
 Set-ADUser -Identity $User1 -Replace @{PrimaryGroupID="2131"}
```

I know I'm likely overthinking things and the answer is right in front of me but lack of sleep (new baby) and staring at code all week has me fried.

Thanx...

Comment: I can't test it myself, but I assume that something like `@{PrimaryGroupID = Get-ADGroup "name" }` would work.

Comment: Why are you changing users' primary group?

Comment: It's part of a "User Disable" script.  Basically, I'm removing all group memberships and leaving only one - Disabled Users.

Comment: mklement0... thank you for the suggestion.  Unfortunately it didn't seem to work.  I get the following error:

Comment: Invalid type 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup'.
Parameter name: PrimaryGroupID
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (user.test:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Comm
   ands.SetADUser
    + PSComputerName        : [DomainController]

Comment: You do not need to change the primary group in order to disable users. Why do you think this is the case?

Comment: "Disabled User" is the name of the group the user get's added to. There's some backend service that runs against that. I don't recall what for though.

Comment: I will need to be more direct and say you should not be changing users' Primary Group.

Comment: Ok. I understand that we shouldn't, but why? What is your reasoning/thought/history in practicing behind changing the primary group?

Comment: Search engines should yield plenty of useful information.

Comment: I've already done an adequate level of searching on the topic and find nothing supporting your argument against changing the users Primary Group - although there's a lot of information on HOW to do it, so you'd think that somewhere in said posts and pages somebody would have stated against it.  So if YOU have an opinion on the subject, please enlighten me!  I am more that open to learning another aspect related.  But if you're telling me not to without cause or reason to support it, that's really just a waist of time.

Comment: My apologies if my previous message sounded confrontational - sincerely not my intention.  I would like to know why changing the Primary Group from the default of "Domain User" to "Disabled User" is a bad thing.  Nothing I read indicates that I shouldn't - only that I don't need to "if not running POSIX applications".  We do, both Mac and FreeBSD systems that use it (but our outside my pervue) by another department.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution! And it wasn't with *Set-ADUser*.  Needed to use *Set-Object* instead.

```
$groupSid = $group.sid $groupSid
[int]$GroupID = $groupSid.Value.Substring($groupSid.Value.LastIndexOf("-")+1)
Get-ADUser $User1 | Set-ADObject -Replace @{primaryGroupID="$GroupID"}
```

Answer (score 0):

So from my original code, using the PrimaryGroupID (2131) directly, worked.

```
Set-ADUser -Identity $User1 -Replace @{PrimaryGroupID = "2131"}
```

So I went the next step and put the Primary Group ID into a variable. This worked and gave me the same result.

```
$group1 = "2131"
Set-ADUser -Identity $User1 -Replace @{PrimaryGroupID = $Group1}
```

I noticed that both "PrimaryGroup" and "DistinguishedName" entry had similar values.

- **PrimaryGroup**: CN=Disabled Users,OU=Disabled,OU=Employees DISABLED,DC=DOMAIN,DC=com
- **DistinguishedName**: CN=Disabled Users,OU=Disabled,OU=Employees DISABLED,DC=DOMAIN,DC=com

So I tried using the Group DistinguishedName in a variable (failed) and directly (failed).

```
$Group1 = (Get-ADGroup 'Disabled Users').DistinguishedName
Set-ADUser -Identity $User1 -Replace @{PrimaryGroup = $Group1}
```